# Matlab: creating input and output dataset for multiple hidden layers of neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Though *newff* usage is deprecated in Matlab, I'm trying to create a neural network for the function **y=x^2** with:

- 1 input layer
- 1 output layer
- 2 hidden layers, with each layer having 4 neurons

The code is as follows (Sample3.m):

```
% providing inputs and outputs  
x=-10:0.1:10;
y=x.*x;

% creating 2 hidden layers with 4 neurons each
hidden_layer_l2=[4 2];

% tansig=transfer function for layer 1
% logsig=transfer function for layer 2
% purelim=transfer function for output layer
network_l2=newff(x,hidden_layer_l2,{'tansig' 'logsig' 'purelin'},'trainlm');
view(network_l2);
net_train_l2=train(network_l2,x,y);

% simulate the data
simulated_data_l2=sim(net_train_l2,x);
plot(x,y,x,simulated_data_l2,'x');
```

The following error popped up:

```
Error using network/train (line 272)
Output data size does not match net.outputs{2}.size.
Error in Sample3 (line 40)
net_train_l2=train(network_l2,x,y);
```

I've browsed through the internet and came to know that I've to supply x*2 matrix to make it work, and currently I'm passing a vector. I'm new to matlab and neural networks and not sure how to make proper input set and output set (x and y).

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: To strengthen what you said about `newff` being depreciated, from the docs: *"Obsoleted in R2010b NNET 7.0.  Last used in R2010a NNET 6.0.4."*. So unless someone who can help is running <R2010b, it will be difficult to write useful code. Can you not use the recommended `feedforwardnet` introduced in R2010b?

Answer (score 0):

```
% Create a Pattern Recognition Network

% net = patternnet(17);  % 1 hidden layer

net = patternnet([17,10]); % 2 hidden layers
```